# Hidden Words in squares

Tags: word-problem, crosswords

I made up this puzzle, so if you are only keen on answering standard puzzles, I am sorry, I thought its been a dull day for questions so I made up my own

Here is a 7 x 7 squares image with 7 8 letter English words hidden in it can you find the words?

[image]

The conditions to be followed are

The first letter of one word has to be the last letter of another, so those letters would be used twice but all other letters have to be used only once per appearance in the square

Each word is formed with letters adjoining them in any one direction, i.e. if one letter is in say second row and second column, the next letter in that word has to be in one of the 8 squares adjoining it

Comment: Woohoo, an actual puzzle. Way to go skv :D A pretty fun one, at that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I managed to find the 7 8-letter words you hid in the grid. Nice little puzzle - no ridiculous words.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beaten me by less than a minute. Pah! :P

Comment: @Joe lol, sorry Joe. It's nice to have a non-chess new puzzle aye? I rushed because I knew someone else would be on it

Comment: oh my god was that too easy

Comment: @skv sod that, it was fun :-)

Comment: @skv yes, it was fun.